# Installed mbstring on php 7.1 but phpinfo says it's not installed - CentOS 7

Tags: php, centos7, mbstring

I've installed php-mbstring on Centos 7 with: yum install php-mbstring and everything seemed to go well please see screenshot below.

I then went to view the phpinfo() output and searched for "mbstring" and it's not showing up as installed. Anyone have a clue why this might be?

[image]

Comment: maybe you've to enable it in the php.ini ?

Comment: Have you restarted apache?

Comment: try `phpenmod mbstring` in terminal of your server

Comment: thanks guys, turns out yes i had to manually enable it in php.ini and restart apache, don't normally have to do that when using yum for things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try restarting Apache:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: ha ha being dumb today, i restarted apache and it's sorted thanks

Comment: I will do i need to wait 3 minutes